# WCF Service Binding - Timeout Configurations

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

Service - WCF Service
Host - Windows Service
Client - ASP.Net Web application

I saw following settings in .config file of client (web application) -

```
closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
```

Can anyone please confirm my undersanding for these Timeout configurations -

```
   closeTimeout="00:01:00"
```

- An error will be thrown by client app if client sends a 'close' request and service takes longer than 1 minute to close gracefully.

  ```
  openTimeout="00:01:00"
  ```
- An error will be thrown by client app if client send an 'open' request and service takes longer than  1 minute to open.

  ```
  receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
  ```
- An error will be thrown by client app if service sends a response and it takes longer than 10 minutes for the client to receive the entire response.

  ```
  sendTimeout="00:01:00"
  ```
- An error will be thrown by client app if client attempts to send a request and it takes longer than 1 minute for the client to transmit that request to service.

Please guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can almost confirm your analysis, except for the receiveTimeout. I think it should be stated as:

- An error will be thrown by the client app if the service is not able to send a response within 10 minutes after the client has performed a successful request for information.

To my knowledge, this is also the reason why, by default, this time is set to 10 minutes instead of 1 minute like for the other timeouts.